# reset field or variable in Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, provider

i'm using provider package for state management , anyone can show me the right way reset  field or variable ?
example code here :  i want to reset _counter back to 0 after i navigate to other screen , i need the right way to do it , thank you in advance :)

```
class AppProvider with ChangeNotifier {
int _counter = 0;
int get counter => _counter;

void incrementCounter() {
_counter++;
notifyListeners();
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this method and call it when you navigate to other page:

```
class AppProvider with ChangeNotifier {
int _counter = 0;
int get counter => _counter;

 void incrementCounter() {
  _counter++;
  notifyListeners();
 }
 void clear(){
  _counter = 0;
  notifyListeners();
 }
}
```

Comment: Mohammad_Asef haha , i did like that too , so is it the right way ?

Comment: Yes, for sure. did it work for you if yes please accept answer

Comment: Mohammad_Asef so no other way to do it or just the way?